# How to Add History to a Firefox Profile

Tags: firefox-profile

I would like to see if I can add history manually. Whether it meant creating a new profile or "managing" the one that's currently being used, it would work. There's currently no tutorial for this on the internet. I've tried everything. Currently all that I see is a Cache with 0-9 and some letters, however I know the history is stored here. I'm not an advanced user, so this is as far as I've been able to get.  Thanks.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? -- adding individual history entries, or importing another profile's history in bulk?

Comment: adding individual history entries

Comment: Have you tried looking on firefoxes support website for any clues?

Answer (score 1):

Close Firefox, locate the [places.sqlite](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Places.sqlite) file in your profile folder and edit it using any SQLite database editor.